# JPanel is not shown after adding it to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have to setup a basic JAVA application including a GUI based on swing.
My idea was to create one JFrame and different JPanels and based on the users input to change the shown JPanel.
After running my application the JFrame is shown but not the content of the JPanel.
I thought up to here it should be strait forward... but as it seems it isn't. Hope you can give me a hint :)

Here is my main:

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
        window.setVisible(true);

        LoginView pane = new LoginView();
        window.getContentPane().add(pane);

        window.invalidate();
        window.repaint();
    }
}
```

my MainWindow:

```
package client;

public class MainWindow extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public MainWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }
    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 352, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 250, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        pack();
    }
}
```

my LoginView:

```
package client.views;

public class LoginView extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    public LoginView() {
        initComponents();
    }
    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void initComponents() {
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1.setText("Login");
        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(345, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(jLabel1)
                .addContainerGap(264, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
}
```

Comment: Call `pack()` again after you add the panel to your frame.

Comment: added `pack()` after adding the panel and before setVisibile but it doesn't help

Comment: try calling .revalidate(); on the top level container, after you have displayed the gui and added all the components

Comment: tried to to call `revalidate()`on the JPanel but also no effect

Comment: call it on window's content pane, thats the top level

Comment: Try both revalidate and repaint as @mKorbel suggests. BTW org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout what is this? Is this a layout manager used by old NetBeans version? What NetBeans version are you on?

Comment: yeah it was from NetBeans. I'm on 7.0.1. Must I care about something when adding stuff and there is is LayoutManager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know the other thing, than calling `revalidate()` and `repaint()`, that I would do is instead of calling `add()` to the current content pane just set a new one.

**I think your issue is related to a incorrect way of adding component to the current content pane.** I think this is the case here, therefore, use the `setContentPane()` method.

Comment: awesome... it works! But in all the tutorials I have seen they used the way via `getContentPane().add()` why I have to it in a different way !?

Comment: You could do it as you did but the important think you have forgotten was to install an appropriate layout manager before calling the `add()` method on `getContentPane()`, for example, the default for `JPanel`, i.e. `FlowLayout`, or preferrable in your case as you want to swap whole current view to use `BorderLayout`.

Comment: ah ok! I tried to set BorderLayout as the LayoutManger before adding and this also works. Thanks man :)

Comment: @trashgod thanks mate this is interesting. I think that with this approach the only problem (argument-al) is that all the panels will be create on start rather then when they are needed, right? PS: +1 right back at you :)

Comment: Exactly right, but the overhead is small. Depending on context, a modal login dialog may be appropriate, too. Edit: Moreover, the OP shouldn't let the GUI designer dictate the design.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, use `CardLayout` to change panels.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
        final JPanel cards = new JPanel(cl);
        cards.add(new LoginView(), "Login");
        cards.add(new MainView(), "Main");
        window.add(cards);
        JPanel control = new JPanel();
        control.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Login") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cl.show(cards, "Main");
            }
        }));
        window.add(control, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class MainView extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public MainView() {
        initComponents();
    }
    ...
}

class LoginView extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    public LoginView() {
        initComponents();
    }
    ...
}
```