# Adding a panel to the main frame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, compiler-errors, frame

I have a main frame named as "frame1". In "frame1" i want to add a panel to display something on the panel but I am not able to add the panel to my main frame i.e "frame1"

```
 public void drawstack()
 {
    JPanel m1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    m1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedSoftBevelBorder());
    m1.setBackground(Color.red);
    frame1.add(m1);
 }
```

This is my code m getting an error at the last line i.e "frame1.add(m1);" error is

```
cannot find symbol : frame1.
```

Comment: Where is frame1 decalred? Show the rest of the code.

Comment: In all likelihood, the frame1 variable is out of scope when trying to use it in the method above -- perhaps it was declared in another method or constructor and thus is only visible in the other method or constructor. It should probably be a class field.

Comment: i also dont see frame1 declared?

Comment: Create the `frame1`, as @Vincent Ramdhanie suggests, or paste [the whole concise example](http://sscce.org) related to the problem. Also if the `m1` serves as the content pane of the frame set it as such using `setContentPane()` method this will [let you avoid issues as for example this one from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11055804/613495).

Comment: "frame1" is the default frame.

Comment: If the class itself is the "frame1" that you are talking about, you can just use `this.add(m1);` or even just `add(m1);`

Comment: rick, "default frame" has no meaning. Please tell us the details of your problem, else we can't help you.

Comment: okk...got the solution...thank u all

Comment: rick please tell also what was the solution.. since you got it :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels *'"default frame" has no meaning'*  Maybe not, but that combined with `frame1` (the number) suggests maybe the OP has multiple frames.  On that matter, the OP should read [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) before proceeding.  Likely to make this problem redundant (disappear).

Comment: i ve put a panel onto "frame1" from the toolbox and named it as "m1" and commented the first and last line of the above code.

Answer (score 1):

frame1 has to be a field in your class or has to be passed as a parameter to your method

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that the compiler cannot find a variable (or class) named `frame1`.  In order for the flagged statement to work you will need to declare a variable named `frame1` and instantiate it with a `JFrame` object, something like this:

```
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame();
frame1.add(m1);
```

*Note*: You can make this variable a member of the class as well if you want to access it from other methods of the same class.

*Note*: The intantiated `JFrame` referenced by `frame1` is initially invisible, you will need to make it visible by calling `setVisible(true)` on it

If your class derives from `JFrame` and you want to add the panel to the frame represented by the current object, you can use the `this` reference instead of `frame1`:

```
this.add(m1);
```

in this ase you can even leave the `this` out:

```
add(m1);
```

Answer (score 0):

obviously theres an error..you haven't initialized a variable named frame1..
 use `this.add(m1);` instead..it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If method you posted is inside your class that extends `JFrame` you need to call

```
getContentPane().add(m1);
```

Also if you want to add more than 1 element to your frame use [layout managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).